# Short dates in .gitconfig

Tags: git, git-config

If I add

```
[format]
  pretty = format:%h %ad %s
```

to my `~/.gitconfig` and enter `git log` I get:

```
36f6ac2 2016-05-22 08:55:55 2016 -0400 Wrapped up optimization of network flow.
37b1037 2016-05-19 07:47:29 2016 -0400 Prepared code to be ready for network flow optimization.
476de11 2016-05-18 18:06:45 2016 -0400 Identified a weakness in the code. Must optimize network flow.
```

If I enter `git log --date=short` I get:

```
36f6ac2 2016-05-22 Wrapped up optimization of network flow.
37b1037 2016-05-19 Prepared code to be ready for network flow optimization.
476de11 2016-05-18 Identified a weakness in the code. Must optimize network flow.
```

Is it possible to set the `--date=short` part permanently in `~/.gitconfig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it short, you can execute

```
git config --global log.date short
```

or manually add this to your `.gitconfig`

```
[log]
    date = short
```